# What is the fastest way to save a pandas dataframe in a MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am writing a code in python to generate and update a mysql table based on another mysql table from another database.

My code does something like this:

For dates in a date_range:

1. Query a quantity in db1 between 2 dates
2. Do some work in pandas => df
3. Delete in db2 the rows with the ids that are in df
4. save df with df.to_sql

The operation 1-2 are taking less than 2s when 3-4 can take up to 10s. Step 4 takes 4 more times than 3. How can I improve my code to make the writing process more efficient

I have already chunked the df for step 3 and 4. I have added `method=multi` in `.to_sql` (this did not work at all). I was wondering if we could do better;

```
with db.begin() as con:
    for chunked in chunks(df.id.tolist(), 1000):
        _ = con.execute(""" DELETE FROM table where id 
                            in {} """.format(to_tuple(chunked)))
    for chunked in chunks(df.id.tolist(), 100000):        
        df.query("id in @chunked").to_sql('table', con, index=False, 
        if_exists='append')
```

thanks for your help

Comment: I had a very similar problem while trying to replicate a SQL Server table into MySQL i.e. how to handle inserts vs updates.  My understanding is that the delete is a heavy task, it was taking hours for me and occasionally locking the table.  I ended up using a MySQL statement like  "INSERT INTO table (column_list)
VALUES (value_list)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   c1 = v1,
   c2 = v2,
   ...;"

Comment: Actually, the longer operation is really the .to_sql I have tried to do `load data infile` and it's 10 to 100 times faster (depending of the number of rows). However, this operation is forbidden on Cloud SQL (managed by google cloud)

Answer (score 0):

I have found `df.to_sql` to be a very slow. One way that I've gotten around it this issue is by outputting the dataframe into a csv file with `df.to_csv` and using BCP in to bluk insert the data in the csv into the table then deleting the csv file once its done with the insertion. You can use subprocess to run BCP in a python script.